# Some Chinese fonts cannot be used in xelatex

Tags: fonts, xetex

I'm using xelatex for I have to deal with Chinese characters. However, something weired bothers me.

```
\usepackage{xeCJK}
...
```

The following command has no bold effect:

```
\textbf{\fontspec{SimSun} 中文}
```

If this is because SimSun have no bold shape, the following problem is much more weired:

```
{\fontspec{STXinwei} 中文}
\textbf{\fontspec{STXinwei} 中文}
```

The former command shows Chinese characters in default font but the latter shows them in STXinwei!

I am using linux and this is my fc-list output

```
/path to my font/ SimSun 宋体:style=regular
/path to my font/ STXinwei 华文新魏:style =regular
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer How do I give you my fonts? They are not built-in

Comment: Check the log file. In general fontspec tells you if it can't create a variant like bold.

Comment: XeTeX will use fallback fonts if the one specified is incomplete. Unless SimSun is a requirement, I recommend another Ming/Song type font like [Source Han Sans](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-serif). Alternatively, [Fandol Song/Kai](https://ctan.org/pkg/fandol) has Song/Ming and Kaiti/Kaishu (standard) style, but probably already part of your installed system. Also check out [Wikipedia's list of CJK fonts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts).

Comment: @svenper you should probably turn that into an answer. It could be quite informative to some future readers.

Answer (score 1):

Using `\textbf` can not give you actual bold font in Chinese, there is a specific bold font for you to use.

Please refer to this [article](http://blog.sina.com.cn/s/blog_61736b5d0100lsm7.html) which explains your problem in its second section.

To summarize on how to apply the Chinese font, there are a few steps you need to go

1. Type in the command line `fc-list :lang=zh-cn | awk '{for (f = 2; f <= NF; ++f) { if (f != 2) {printf("%s", OFS);} printf("%s", $f)}; printf "\n"}' | sort -d > chinese.txt` and run to get a list of Chinese font you installed in your laptop.
2. Then in the text file it produced, find the font you would like to use, say `Weibei SC,魏碑\-簡,魏碑\-简:style=Bold,粗體,粗体`.
3. Then in the preamble of your `.tex` file, type `\usepackage{ctex}` and `\newCJKfontfamily\weibei{Weibei SC}`, where *Weibei SC* is the font name which you can see in step 2.
4. Last, in the body of the article, you can start using the font with `\weibei`.

Comment: Can you summarise the main information from the article you link to? This would ensure the usefulness of your answer even in case the link breaks

Comment: @samcarter Sure, I will include an example this evening. Thanks for reminding.